# Extract substring from string using Python and regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing very long strings in the 'page' column that I am trying to extract a substring from:

*Example string:* /ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&**search_query=example one**&y=0&x=0

Using regex, I am having a hard time determining how to extract the string between the two ampersands and removing all other characters part of the greater string.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

dataset = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\example.xlsx')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

dataframe['Page'] = format = re.search(r'&(.*)&',str(dataframe['Page']))

dataframe.to_excel(r'C\Users\output.xlsx)
```

The code above runs but does not output anything to my new spreadsheet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's always helpful to include some sample data as text. The easiest way to do this is paste the output of `df.head()` into a code block in your questions

Comment: Something like `dataframe.Page.str.split("&").str[1]`?

Comment: Probably, `dataframe['Page'].str.extract(r'&([^&]+)&')` will do.

Comment: Also, parsing a string representation of the dataframe is just asking for trouble. Instead operate on the series of strings.

Comment: These strings are not representations of the dataframe, I think. For column 'Page', there are a couple thousands of rows, each cell containing a string like the example.

Comment: @KwesiC: When you do `str(...)` you actually turn it into one gigantic string, which might not even contain all the rows (it only shows the first few, then some dots and then the last, have a look at e.g. `str(pd.Series(range(100000)))` to see this). Instead you need to operate on every element of the column, e.g. with `apply`.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the query string from the URL with [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse), then parse it with [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> path = '/ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&search_query=example one&y=0&x=0'
>>> query_string = urlparse(path).query  
>>> parse_qs(query)
{'search_query': ['example one'], 'y': ['0'], 'x': ['0']}
```

**EDIT:** To extract the `query_string` from all pages in the `Page` column:

```
dataframe['Page'] = dataframe['Page'].apply(lambda page: parse_qs(urlparse(page).query)['search_query'][0])
```

Comment: You might want to add that this should be used like `dataframe.Page.apply(parse_qs)` or similar.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this programmatically? I have a few thousands of rows of data with every cell being a unique string.

Comment: So, you want to extract the value of `query_string` from each path?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, sir. This is the solution I have had success with.

Comment: I updated the answer a bit. Turns out, the query string needs to be extracted first before passing it to `parse_qs`. Given the structure of your data, this was not necessary, but it would break for different inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```
(?<=&).*?(?=&)
```

> Explanation

- `(?<=&)` - Positive lookbehind. Matches `&`.
- `(.*?)` - Matches anything except newline. (Lazy method).
- `(?=&)` - Positive lookahead matches `&`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZjLs7l/3)

Answer (score 0):

Fast and efficient pandas method.

Example data:

```
temp,page
1,  /ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&search_query=example one&y=0&x=0
2,  /ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&search_query=example one&y=0&x=0
3,  /ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&search_query=example one&y=0&x=0
```

Code:

```
df = example.data # from above
df["query"] = df['page'].str.split("&", expand=True)[1].str.split("=", expand=True)[1]
print(df)
```

Example output:

```
   temp  \
0  1          
1  2          
2  3          

                                                                                                          page  \
0    /ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&search_query=example one&y=0&x=0   
1    /ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&search_query=example one&y=0&x=0   
2    /ex/search/!tu/p/z1/zVJdb4IwFP0r88HH0Sp-hK/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?s&search_query=example one&y=0&x=0   

         query  
0  example one  
1  example one  
2  example one
```

If you would like to label your columns based on the key=value pair, that would be a different extract afterwords.